How to compare XML layout with a XML Fiscal note with python
As a beginer in development and here, is it possible that I'm in the wrong topic, if that's the case, sorry. I've been working on a Python script that verifies if a XML Fiscal Note is compatible with a XML Layout, with import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET I can did the scritp verify if the tags of both XML are similar, but, now, I want to improve the script to verify if the order of the tags is the same, but has another problemas :D, some layouts accepts some notes even when the layout are not exactly the same. For example, if the first tag of the note is not in the file or another tag is into the file.
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# Function to calculate similarity between two sets
def calculate_similarity(set1, set2):
    intersection = set1.intersection(set2)
    smallest_set_size = min(len(set1), len(set2))
    if smallest_set_size == 0:
        return 0
    similarity = len(intersection) / smallest_set_size
    return similarity


# Function to validate a fiscal note against the layouts
def validate_fiscal_note(fiscal_note_xml, similarity_threshold=0.1):
    fiscal_note_tree = ET.parse(fiscal_note_xml)
    fiscal_note_root = fiscal_note_tree.getroot()
    
    fiscal_note_tags = {child.tag for child in fiscal_note_root.iter()}

    best_match_code = None
    best_match_similarity = 0
    best_match_code_list = []

    for code, layout_tags in layouts_dict.items():
        similarity = calculate_similarity(layout_tags, fiscal_note_tags)
        best_match_code_list.append({'code': code, 'similarity': similarity})
    
    sorted_list = sorted(best_match_code_list, key=lambda x: x['similarity'])

    if not sorted_list:
        return 'Any layout was finded'
    else:
        return sorted_list

# Parse the layouts XML
layouts_tree = ET.parse('layouts.xml')
layouts_root = layouts_tree.getroot()

# Build a dictionary of layouts
layouts_dict = {}
for layout in layouts_root:
    layout_code = layout.attrib['code']  # Make sure this matches your XML structure; might need to adjust
    tags = {child.tag for child in layout}
    layouts_dict[layout_code] = tags

# Validate the fiscal note and print the result
result = validate_fiscal_note('Nota 2.xml')
print(result[-5:])

How can I handle it? To verify the order of the tags and similarity, but accept when the note is not too different of the layout?

Welcome to SO! For a [mre], please post sample XML(s) and not just a block of code.

Also, if you need to check exact adherence of an XML to a specific layout, consider the XML Schema Definition (XSD). Python has several solutions for this validation which requires setting up an .xsd file. Not sure if this resolves your near similarity needs though.

It's possible to compare both files using pyxml2xpath package to obtain all possible XPath expressions from both.
Order of the elements can be checked also.
pip install pyxml2xpath==0.3.3
from xml2xpath import xml2xpath

tree, nsmap, xmap = xml2xpath.parse('/home/luis/tmp/S1.xml')

tree2, nsmap2, xmap2 = xml2xpath.parse('/home/luis/tmp/S2.xml')

if xmap == xmap2:
    print("Identical structure", len(xmap.items()), len(xmap2.items()))
else:
    print("Different structure")

print("")

xmap2values= list(xmap2.items())
for i, x in enumerate(xmap.items()):
    if x != xmap2values[i]:
        print(f"Xpath order mismatch: {x[0]} - {xmap2values[i][0]}")
    else:
        print(f"Xpath match: {x[0]} - {xmap2values[i][0]}")
        c1 = tree.xpath(f"{x[0]}/text()")[0]
        c2 = tree2.xpath(f"{xmap2values[i][0]}/text()")[0]
        if c1 != c2:
            print(f"Content mismatch: content1= '{c1}' - content2 = '{c2}'")

Given these documents
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <ele1>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <child2>2</child2>
  </ele1>
  <ele2>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <child2>2</child2>
  </ele2>
</root>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<root>
  <ele1>
    <child1>1</child1>
    <child2>different content</child2>
  </ele1>
  <ele2>
    <child2>2</child2>
    <child1>1</child1>
  </ele2>
</root>

Result
Different structure    
Xpath match: /root - /root
Xpath match: /root/ele1 - /root/ele1
Xpath match: /root/ele1/child1 - /root/ele1/child1
Xpath match: /root/ele1/child2 - /root/ele1/child2
Content mismatch: content1= '2' - content2 = 'different content'
Xpath match: /root/ele2 - /root/ele2
Xpath order mismatch: /root/ele2/child1 - /root/ele2/child2
Xpath order mismatch: /root/ele2/child2 - /root/ele2/child1

Each dicitonary item contains:
"xpath": [ 
    "resolved xpath", 
    # count of found elements with resolved xpath
    <number>,
    # element attributes dictionary
    {...}
 ]

Note: I'm the author of pyxml2xpath.
